# BingMapsRESTToolkit - SnapToRoadRequest returns BingMapsRESTToolkit.Route

Tags: c#, bing-maps

When I make the request in Postman, I get a response that contains a RouteProxyAsyncResult with a callback URL:

```
        "resources": [
            {
                "__type": "RouteProxyAsyncResult:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1",
                "callbackInSeconds": 3,
                "callbackUrl": "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/SnapToRoadAsyncCallback?.....",
                "errorMessage": "Request accepted",
                "isAccepted": true,
                "isCompleted": false,
                "requestId": "XXXXX"
            }
        ]
```

I can then get a RequestURL, then the SnapToRoadResponse.

When I use `BingMapsRESTToolkit SnapToRoadRequest` as follows:

```
        SnapToRoadRequest r = new SnapToRoadRequest()
        {
            Points = Coordinates,
            IncludeSpeedLimit = true,
            IncludeTruckSpeedLimit = true,
            Interpolate = true,
            SpeedUnit = SpeedUnitType.MPH,
            TravelMode = TravelModeType.Driving,
            BingMapsKey = bingMapsKey
        };
        Response response = await r.Execute();
```

I get a response with a SnapToRoadResponse if the amount is 100 or under, but if the amount is above 100, I get the following:

```
[0] {BingMapsRESTToolkit.Route} BingMapsRESTToolkit.Resource {BingMapsRESTToolkit.Route}
```

I want to get a `SnapToRoadResponse` from it, or a `BingMapsRESTToolkit.AsyncStatus`, so I can get the `SnapToRoadResponse` from it. How do I stop it sending back a Route object?